# how to add 'OR' operator in views sort criteria

Tags: views

How to add `'OR' operator` in views sort criteria?

Is there any ui setting or have to do some custom work?

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean add OR? There is no such condition in sorting. You can have different sorting levels. Add multiple values in the view's ui sorting criteria and then re-arrange properly.